# How to query a remote snappydata server from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, snappydata

I am trying to query snappydata from Python and some of the answers say in StackOverflow that Python cant connect to remote spark clusters. Could anyone help me how can I connect to snappydata cluster and get a simple query working?

Code I am trying -

```
from pyspark.sql.snappy import SnappySession
snappy = SnappySession.builder.appName("test")  \
                              .master("local[*]") \
                              .config("spark.snappydata.connection", "<remote server>:1527") \
                              .getOrCreate()
```

I am getting FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified. In running above code. Unfortunately, there is not much information in setting up the environment. However, I have configured my environment to run PySpark locally and it works.

Answer (score 0):

SnappyData's Python API is not distributed as a Python module that you can use from any spark cluster. However, you can use PySpark that is bundled as part of the SnappyData distribution.